# How do I write a Stored Procedure about calculating total price in inventory

Tags: sql-server

I'm kind of new and learning Microsoft SQL. So I have these 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE Char_item(
char_id    VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL REFERENCES Character(char_id) ON DELETE 
CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
item_id    VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL REFERENCES Item(item_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON 
UPDATE CASCADE,
item_qty    INTEGER    NOT NULL    CHECK(item_qty >= 0),
PRIMARY KEY(char_id, item_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Item(
item_id            VARCHAR(5)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
item_name        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
item_desc        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
unit_price        FLOAT NOT NULL,
armor_id        VARCHAR(5)    REFERENCES Armor(armor_id) ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
weapon_id        VARCHAR(5)    REFERENCES Weapon(weapon_id) ON DELETE 
CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

char_item has the item and its quantity for each item in the inventory
while item table holds the unit_price per item.

I want to create a stored procedure that helps me in getting the TOTAL PRICE of my ENTIRE inventory
using SELECT item_id will give me all item_ids in one go which I don't want because then I won't be able to calculate the total price for each specific item found in the inventory.

I was thinking about making a loop but I am kind of stuck into how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by "total price of my entire inventory"? If prices are determined by each item, you want to sum each item price multiplied by it's quantity, for all items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty basic aggregation. Something like this should be what you are looking for. When you start thinking loop....step back and rethink because looping is almost always NOT what you want to do.

```
select TotalInventoryValue = SUM(ci.item_qty * i.unit_price)
from Item i
join Char_item ci on ci.item_id = i.item_id
```

Comment: Be careful with this query. This does not work if there are multiple characters, as it will give you the total inventory value for everybody, not just one character.

Comment: @Dogs - I don't understand your concern. The OP wanted the entire inventory, not a single item.

Comment: First column of the first table is char_id, and it references a Character table. If there are 5 characters, all 5 of those character's items will be in the Char_item table, not just the items of the character we're looking for.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the question where the OP mentions anything about wanting data for only a single character. But sure it isn't exactly a big leap that if they want data for only a character to add a where predicate to the query.

Comment: @Dogs Sorry for the confusion, I indeed know how to easily fetch data for a specific item by using WHERE condition. What I didn't know was how to gather all items together and fetch the total price of the ENTIRE inventory by looking each item's unit price in the item table. I did not know you could insert equations inside the SUM() braces directly, and I was able to get the answer to that which greatly helps me complete my Normalization project.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you're going to need to do what is called a JOIN. You will want to line up the row in the Char_Item table with the corresponding row in the Item table, so that you have the quantity and the price available together.

```
SELECT * FROM Item
JOIN Char_item ON Char_item.item_id = Item.item_id
```

This will yield a result set that has all of the columns from both Char_item and Item for a given item id. Something like this:

```
|char_id|item_id|item_qty|item_id|item_name|item_desc|unit_price|armor_id|weapon_id|
```

Of course, you don't need all of those columns. For each item in your inventory, you really just need the item_qty and the unit_price:

```
SELECT Char_item.item_qty, Item.unit_price FROM Item
JOIN Char_item ON Char_item.item_id = Item.item_id
```

Now we have all of the data we need. Time to work towards calculating what we want. Let's start by calculating for each item how much total value we have from that item.

```
SELECT Char_item.item_qty * Item.unit_price FROM Item
JOIN Char_item ON Char_item.item_id = Item.item_id
```

We're closer, but we want the value of ALL of the items, not just the value of all of the Blue Shirts, so we want to aggregate. One of the simplest aggregations we can do is a SUM, which is exactly what we want. It will go down our rows and add up each column into a total.

```
SELECT SUM(Char_item.item_qty * Item.unit_price) FROM Item
JOIN Char_item ON Char_item.item_id = Item.item_id
```

This query works well if we only have one Character. If we have more than one Character, however, it's not telling us the total value of a character's inventory. It's telling us the total value of all characters inventories. We should probably narrow it down.

```
SELECT Char_item.char_id, SUM(Char_item.item_qty * Item.unit_price) FROM Item
JOIN Char_item ON Char_item.item_id = Item.item_id
GROUP BY Char_item.char_id
```

This new query is telling us for each character, how much total value in inventory they have. If you want to see everybody, you can look at this result. But maybe you just want a specific character's inventory. Let's say the character you're interested in is Character with id 5. We can tell it we only want inventory items for Character 5

```
SELECT Char_item.char_id, SUM(Char_item.item_qty * Item.unit_price) FROM Item
JOIN Char_item ON Char_item.item_id = Item.item_id
WHERE Char_item.char_id = 5
GROUP BY Char_item.char_id
```

In this case, since there's only one char_id, we don't need to include the GROUP BY, so you could get rid of that, but I wanted to include the GROUP BY example so that you're aware of how that works.

```
SELECT Char_item.char_id, SUM(Char_item.item_qty * Item.unit_price) FROM Item
JOIN Char_item ON Char_item.item_id = Item.item_id
WHERE Char_item.char_id = 5
```

I would recommend running these different queries and exploring the different results they produce in order to see if you can get the results you're expecting.